How to break the data at certain values in order to plot different lines in base R?
I have this data of a woman's basal temperature. I have three columns: date, temperature and day of her menstrual cycle.
I want to plot with lines temperature (y-axis) against the "day of her cycle" (x axis). For every "First day" (menstruation day), I want the line to break and possible change color,
without having to separate the data set in pieces. The data is messy, not every month the values were recorded, but we can see that if the day decreses, then it is allready a different period.
The data looks like this:
Date    Temp    DayofCycle

17/06/2024  98.06   16
18/06/2024  98.42   17
19/06/2024  98.68   18
21/06/2024  98.97   20
22/06/2024  98.63   21
24/06/2024  98.16   23
25/06/2024  98.73   24
27/06/2024  98.29   26

28/06/2024  97.87   1
01/07/2024  98.26   4
03/07/2024  97.94   6
04/07/2024  98.07   7
05/07/2024  97.41   8
08/07/2024  97.99   11
09/07/2024  98.06   12
10/07/2024  97.92   13
11/07/2024  98.28   14
12/07/2024  98.17   15
13/07/2024  98.22   16
14/07/2024  98.64   17
16/07/2024  98.88   19
18/07/2024  98.32   21
21/07/2024  98.44   24
24/07/2024  98.46   27

25/07/2024  98.17   1
27/07/2024  98.11   3
28/07/2024  98.16   4
29/07/2024  98.66   5
31/07/2024  98.04   7
03/08/2024  97.73   10  
05/08/2024  97.35   12
06/08/2024  97.36   13
08/08/2024  98.01   14

I want to use base R for the plot (no ggplot for now).


Convert your Date column to Date class with as.Date(). 2. Add a grouping variable that has a unique value for each line you want to draw, perhaps with your_data$group = cumsum(c(-1, sign(diff(your_data$DayOfCycle))) == -1) (though note that this will fail if, e.g., the first day of cycle on one month is higher than the last day of cycle in the previous month due to missingness).  3. Use a for loop to draw lines for each group. If you need more help than that, please show your best attempt and explain where you are stuck.


Create a "cycle" variable based on the day of cycle being less than its previous value, then split the data on cycle and use lines to plot the data.
df$cycle <- 1+cumsum(df$DayofCycle < dplyr::lag(df$DayofCycle, default=FALSE))
cols <- rainbow(length(unique(df$cycle)))
  
plot(Temp~DayofCycle, data=df, type="n", las=1, main="Plot of temperature vs day of cycle")

invisible(
  lapply(split(df, df$cycle), \(x) {
  lines(x$Temp~x$DayofCycle, col=cols[x$cycle], lwd=2) }
  )
)

legend("topleft", legend=paste("Cycle", unique(df$cycle)), 
       col=cols, lty=1, lwd=2, bty="n")




Data:
df <- structure(list(Date = c("18/06/2024", "19/06/2024", "21/06/2024", 
"22/06/2024", "24/06/2024", "25/06/2024", "27/06/2024", "28/06/2024", 
"01/07/2024", "03/07/2024", "04/07/2024", "05/07/2024", "08/07/2024", 
"09/07/2024", "10/07/2024", "11/07/2024", "12/07/2024", "13/07/2024", 
"14/07/2024", "21/07/2024", "24/07/2024", "25/07/2024", "27/07/2024", 
"28/07/2024", "29/07/2024", "31/07/2024", "03/08/2024", "05/08/2024", 
"06/08/2024", "08/08/2024"), Temp = c(98.42, 98.68, 98.97, 98.63, 
98.16, 98.73, 98.29, 97.87, 98.26, 97.94, 98.07, 97.41, 97.99, 
98.06, 97.92, 98.28, 98.17, 98.22, 98.64, 98.44, 98.46, 98.17, 
98.11, 98.16, 98.66, 98.04, 97.73, 97.35, 97.36, 98.01), DayofCycle = c(17, 
18, 20, 21, 23, 24, 26, 1, 4, 6, 7, 8, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 
17, 24, 27, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 10, 12, 13, 14)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-30L))


I used Gregor's lagged group measure, but skipped the loop and simply made three datasets. Is this what you're looking for?
menst<-structure(list(Date = c("17/06/2024", "18/06/2024", "19/06/2024", 
"21/06/2024", "22/06/2024", "24/06/2024", "25/06/2024", "27/06/2024", 
NA, "28/06/2024", "01/07/2024", "03/07/2024", "04/07/2024", "05/07/2024", 
"08/07/2024", "09/07/2024", "10/07/2024", "11/07/2024", "12/07/2024", 
"13/07/2024", "14/07/2024", "16/07/2024", "18/07/2024", "21/07/2024", 
"24/07/2024", NA, "25/07/2024", "27/07/2024", "28/07/2024", "29/07/2024", 
"31/07/2024", "03/08/2024", "05/08/2024", "06/08/2024", "08/08/2024"
), Temp = c("98.0", "98.4", "98.6", "98.9", "98.6", "98.1", "98.7", 
"98.2", NA, "97.8", "98.2", "97.9", "98.0", "97.4", "97.9", "98.0", 
"97.9", "98.2", "98.1", "98.2", "98.6", "98.8", "98.3", "98.4", 
"98.4", NA, "98.1", "98.1", "98.1", "98.6", "98.0", "97.7", "97.3", 
"97.3", "98.0"), CycleDay = c("16", "17", "18", "20", "21", "23", 
"24", "26", NA, "1", "4", "6", "7", "8", "11", "12", "13", "14", 
"15", "16", "17", "19", "21", "24", "27", NA, "1", "3", "4", 
"5", "7", "10", "12", "13", "14")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -35L))

menst$Date<-as.Date(menst$Date,format="%d/%m/%Y") # format date
menst$CycleDay<-as.numeric(menst$CycleDay) # format cycle day
menst<-menst %>% arrange(Date)  # ensure date order
menst$group = cumsum(c(-1, sign(diff(menst$CycleDay))) == -1)

menst1<-menst[menst$group==1,]  # data set for each cycle
menst2<-menst[menst$group==2,]
menst3<-menst[menst$group==3,]


plot(menst$CycleDay,menst$Temp,
 xlab="Basal Temperature", ylab="Cycle Day",
 main="So much science...",
 font.main=9)
 lines(menst1$CycleDay,menst1$Temp,type="l", col="red")
 lines(menst2$CycleDay,menst2$Temp,type="l", col='orange')
 lines(menst3$CycleDay,menst3$Temp,type="l", col='blue')


I assume OP shared a sample of data. Making separate data sets works okay for 2 or 3, but if they have more months of data it gets to be a real pain. I'd strongly suggest a loop or similar for generality.
